# How can I get the last commit in all tags?

Tags: git

I've just made a commit in my project, and I was creating a tag in every step, but it seems the last commit was done in some of this tags. The thing is that I can not longer see my latest change from a minutes ago. How can I checkout in my last commit no mater what tags are in my project? I need the last one. Any help?

This is what I was doing:

1. Coding a simple *login module* at 60%
2. Making commit for the 60% of login module (after git add -A) `git commit -m "login module to 60%"`
3. Finishing coding login module at 100%
4. Creating a tag with: git tag -a myTag-01 -m "Login module finished"
5. And so on...

Comment: you were adding tags for every commit?

Comment: @GuillemoMansilla after some changes I was making commits. after a task complete let's say 'login-functionality' I've created a tag called 'step-login'

Comment: "Last commit" is ambiguous - are you looking at it from an ancestral or chronological standpoint?  (Do you want the last thing you committed regardless of what day it was created, or do you want the thing that was created on the most recent day?  If you get into rebasing there can be a difference between the two.)

Comment: @Makoto The thing is that I don't know in wich tag I was made commmit 10 minutes ago, I think that I need the last thing I've commited regardless of what day it was created.

Comment: @Makoto It's worth noting that even asking for the "last" commit in either the topological sense or the chronological sense is ambiguous: two commits may be at "equivalent positions" in the commit DAG, and two commits may have exactly the same timestamps (even though that's very unlikely to happen in practice).

Comment: possible point of mis-communication - by "creating a tag", do you mean you run `git tag .....` every time you make a commit, or are you referring to some sort of meta-data tag that you are including in your commit messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply checkout the name of the branch for which you need the last commit. So if you are working on `master`, do `git checkout master`.

(**Edit**: after getting more illumination of the problem from the comments, it is not as easy as above).

OK, so my guess is that you committed while in a detached HEAD state. What this means is that you were not really on a branch when you committed, so there is nothing pointing to your last commit; you need to find it. Do this by doing a `git reflog`. This will show you, among other things, your recent commits. Find the one closest to the top that looks like a commit (i.e. one that has a commit message). The hash will be listed next to it; use that to do a `git checkout <hash>`.

So now you that you are on your commit, you have a few choices. What you *should* do is create a branch that points to that commit with `git checkout -b branch-name`. An alternative would be to just tag it, like it seems you have been doing. The advantage of making a new branch is that every time you commit on that branch, the branch will be advanced to that commit, so you don't run into these kinds of problems again.

Also, I would **strongly** recommend you give the [Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) a solid read. It will make your life a whole lot easier going forward.

(**Edit2**)

By the way, if you *really* tagged your last commit, you can list all the tags with `git tag -l`, and get the hash that way as well. In fact, once you know the tag name, you can just `git checkout <tag-name>`.

Comment: The thing is that I don't know in wich tag I was made commmit 10 minutes ago.

Comment: You don't need to know the tag, just the branch. When you do `git status`, what do you see? Also, if you do `git branch`, you can see all the branches in your repo.

Comment: ´HEAD detached at mytag-11
nothing to commit, working directory clean´

Comment: And when you do `git branch`, what do you see?

Comment: * <detached from mytag-10>
master

Comment: Since `master` is your only branch, then the solution in my answer (`git checkout master`) will get you to your last commit.

Comment: Nope, is not working for me after do 'git checkout master' and writ 'git log' in the console I just see commits for the last friday, and I've commited my project 30 minutes ago.

Comment: OK, edited my answer to reflect what I think is going on in your situation.